# Interface the BTreeMap and HashMap in Rust

Tags: rust, recursive-datastructures

I am implementing a tree data structure. My idea to do this is to have a `struct Tree` that have `children:SomeMapType<Tree>` field to keep track of its children nodes, where `SomeMapType` may be `BTreeMap`, `HashMap` or something else. So instead, I would like it be polymorphic on the map type I choose to use.

Code as follows:

```rust
trait Map {
    type Key;
    type Value;
    fn new() -> Self;
}

struct Tree<Symbol, MapType>
where
    MapType: Map<Key = Symbol, Value = Box<Self>>,
{
    children: MapType,
}

impl<Symbol, MapType> Tree<Symbol, MapType>
where
    MapType: Map<Key = Symbol, Value = Box<Self>>,
{
    fn new() -> Self {
        Self {
            children: Map::new(),
        }
    }
}
impl<Key,Value> Map for std::collections::BTreeMap<Key,Value> {
    type Key = Key;
    type Value = Value;
    fn new() -> Self {
        Self::new()
    }
}
```

So far, so good. However, when I am to use this data type, e.g., calling the `new` function, by instantiating with a specific map, say `BTreeMap`, like follows :

```rust
fn main() {
    let tree = Tree::<u8,std::collections::BTreeMap<u8,_>>::new();
}
```

it compiles to an error message :

```
error[E0271]: type mismatch resolving `<BTreeMap<u8, _> as Map>::Value == Box<Tree<u8, BTreeMap<u8, _>>>`
   --> src/zips.rs:162:16
    |
162 |     let tree = Tree::<u8,std::collections::BTreeMap<u8,_>>::new();
    |                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ type mismatch resolving `<BTreeMap<u8, _> as Map>::Value == Box<Tree<u8, BTreeMap<u8, _>>>`
    |
note: cyclic type of infinite size
   --> src/zips.rs:155:18
    |
155 |     type Value = Value;
    |                  ^^^^^
note: required by a bound in `Tree`
   --> src/zips.rs:136:32
    |
134 | struct Tree<Symbol, MapType>
    |        ---- required by a bound in this struct
135 | where
136 |     MapType: Map<Key = Symbol, Value = Box<Self>>,
    |                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ required by this bound in `Tree`
```

My guess is that there is some trouble for the rust compiler to reason at that location about recursive types. My question is then how to actually achieve putting an interface that masks the implementation (`BTreeMap` or `HashMap`) details in my case.

Comment: What you're essentially trying to do is allow the user to specify that they wish to use a `BTreeMap` without having to specify that the map's value type is `Box<Tree<...>>`.  There are broadly two ways that you could go about this: (1) have the user specify a selection type of your own making eg `UseBTreeMap` that doesn't have a value parameter; or (2) use the actual `BTreeMap` with a known/dummy value parameter such as the unit type `()`.  A third hybrid option would be to make `UseBTreeMap` a type alias for the latter.

Comment: In any event, you could then use a GAT to defer reifying the actual value type until construction site: e.g. https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=b524de5b2e185f6cf24a69bc56e60ed7

Comment: Also note being "generic" over either `HashMap` or `BTreeMap` is a very odd thing to do, since `HashMap` requires that it's keys are `Hash`, and `BTreeMap` requires it's keys are `Ord`. If you want to use either one you assure that keys are both `Hash` and `Ord`, which might not be what your users would want.

Comment: Instead of the GAT approach shown above, you can also just parameterise the `Map` trait by `Value`: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=bae1b7c207ed5d367648d0c1ec3853d0

Comment: @eggyal Both of your solutions are insanely eye-opening for me. This seems to mean that by using traits and markers (in your case `BTreeMap<Key,()>`, we can defer the actualization of type parameters to when it is actually needed. But in my case, this is just a good solution to avoid infinite type name situations. Thank you! Please post it as an answer so I can accept it as the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I post the same question on the Rust-Lang forum, and [this answer](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/interface-the-btreemap-and-hashmap/97937/7) deal with my problem almost perfectly. To be self-contained, I copy-paste the code from there, the code completely thanks to steffahn user from the forum.

```rust
trait MapKind<Key, Value> {
    type MapType: Map<Key = Key, Value = Value>;
}

trait Map {
    type Key;
    type Value;
    fn new() -> Self;
    fn insert(&mut self, key: Self::Key, value: Self::Value);
}

struct Tree<Symbol, MK>
where
    MK: MapKind<Symbol, Box<Self>>,
{
    children: MK::MapType,
}

impl<Symbol, MK> Tree<Symbol, MK>
where
    MK: MapKind<Symbol, Box<Self>>,
{
    fn new() -> Self {
        Self {
            children: Map::new(),
        }
    }
}

impl<Key: Ord, Value> Map for std::collections::BTreeMap<Key, Value> {
    type Key = Key;
    type Value = Value;
    fn new() -> Self {
        Self::new()
    }
    fn insert(&mut self, key: Key, value: Value) {
        self.insert(key, value);
    }
}

struct BTreeMap_;

impl<Key: Ord, Value> MapKind<Key, Value> for BTreeMap_ {
    type MapType = std::collections::BTreeMap<Key, Value>;
}

fn main() {
    let tree = Tree::<u8, BTreeMap_>::new();
}
```

@eggyal also comes up with the same idea, but more complete, by giving me two methods, one using generic traits and the other using generalized associated type in trait.

#### EDIT

I come back after trying to digest these great answers a bit, in the framework of proof theory. I rename some of the identifiers as follows:

```rust
use std::collections::BTreeMap;

// A proposition stating that `ThatType<Key,Value>` implements the anonymously defined map interface
trait SomeTypeImplementsMapInterface {
    type ThatType<Key,Value>;
    
    // an anonymous definition of MapInterface as follows (the total of all specified behaviors in the trait)
    fn new<Key,Value>() -> Self::ThatType<Key,Value>;
}

/// A proof that BTreeMap implements the (anonymous) map interface
struct AProofThatBTreeMapImplementsMapInterface;
impl SomeTypeImplementsMapInterface for AProofThatBTreeMapImplementsMapInterface {
    type ThatType<Key,Value> = BTreeMap<Key,Value>;

    fn new<Key,Value>() -> Self::ThatType<Key,Value> {
        BTreeMap::new()
    }
}
 
struct Tree<Symbol,ProofThatSomeTypeImplementsMapInterface: SomeTypeImplementsMapInterface> {
    children: ProofThatSomeTypeImplementsMapInterface::ThatType<Symbol,Box<Self>>,
}

impl<Symbol,ProofThatSomeTypeImplementsMapInterface: SomeTypeImplementsMapInterface> Tree<Symbol,ProofThatSomeTypeImplementsMapInterface> {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Self {
            children: ProofThatSomeTypeImplementsMapInterface::new(),
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let tree = Tree::<u8,AProofThatBTreeMapImplementsMapInterface>::new();
}
```